# Why doesn't mutate and recode print correctly?

Tags: r

I'm using mutate to try and recode some data in a data set. I have used a similar method earlier on in my work and it worked fine.

Now when I use it, the code runs fine with no error messages but doesn't change the data when I print it.

I tried the following code (I deleted some data to simplify it for this question)

```
psqi_data<- psqi_data %>% dplyr::mutate(., HSE = dplyr::recode(HSE,
"30.43478" =3,
"31.57895"=3,
"66.66667"=2,
"67.92453"=2,
"68.96552"=2,
"70.00000"=2,
"70.58824"=2,
"75.00000"=1,
"76.47059"=1,
"76.74419"=1,
"76.92308"=1,
"77.41935"=1,
"109.09091"=0,
"114.28571"=0,
"120.00000"=0,
"150.00000"=0 ))
```

but when i do view(psqi_data), not all the data has been recoded.

Comment: It could be that the precision is not exact as these are floats.  Instead use either `cut` or `findInterval`

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of not matching exactly the values as `recode` looks for an exact match and the column seems to be float.  So, precision could be a factor.  We may either `round` the column and use the function

```
psqi_data<- psqi_data %>% dplyr::mutate(HSE = dplyr::recode(round(HSE, 2),
"30.43" =3,
"31.58"=3,
"66.67"=2,
"67.92"=2,
"68.96"=2,
"70.00"=2,
"70.59"=2,
"75.00"=1,
"76.47"=1,
"76.74"=1,
"76.92"=1,
"77.42"=1,
"109.10"=0,
"114.29"=0,
"120.00"=0,
"150.00"=0 ))
```

---

or use `cut` or `findInterval`

```
psqi_data <- psqi_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(HSE = as.integer(cut(-HSE, breaks = c(-Inf, -150, -77.41935,
     -70.58824, -31.57895, Inf))) - 1)
```

Comment: I just also tried using this findinterval method and its recoding all my values to 16?

Comment: @Ella We don't have a small reproducible example for testing, but it shouldn't be the case with `findInterval` if the values are in those ranges and the column class is numeric